# hCatalog page gives error

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, hcatalog

I am using HortonWorks sandbox to try out few samples. Following page is displaying "Error" on UI (Time Out) http://:8000/hcatalog/

Detailed Server logs:

> [25/Apr/2014 13:07:49 +0000] middleware INFO   Processing exception: timed out (code THRIFTSOCKET): None:
>    Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/djang‌​o/core/handlers/base.py", line 100, in get_response response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Any advice?

Comment: Detailed Server logs - [25/Apr/2014 13:07:49 +0000] middleware   INFO     Processing exception: timed out (code THRIFTSOCKET): None: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 100, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is due to memory. Your memory should be at least 4096 MB.